# Preventing MS SQL Server data files from being used on other servers

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to encrypt or password protect MSSQL Server database files so that they can not be used  in case they were detached and attached to other DB servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of SQL Server? From 2008 onward, this could be of interest to you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(SQL.100).aspx.

That said, you can of course use standard Windows NTFS features: ACLs and file-level encryption.

Comment: Do keep in mind that if this is an application which you are selling to customers, the data within the database is theirs and they can do with it as they please.  And that includes moving the database from one server to another.